# Finding occurrences of words in text which are in a list words

Tags: python, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Say I have a list of allowed words/phrases:

```
'Stack'
'Overflow'
'Stack Overflow'
'Stack Exchange'
'Exchange'
```

and the following text to parse:

```
'Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. 
 Here are some words which should match: Stack, Exchange.'
```

I'd like to get the list of words which are found in the allowed list:

- 'Stack Overflow'
- 'Stack'
- 'Exchange'

What would be the best way to achieve the result?

The allowed list I'll be using could be at least a thousand words/phrases.

Comment: Seems like this answer from another question has some interesting pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3261300/89391

Comment: Do you know how what the largest number of words in a phrase will be?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll try out the possible solutions, though re-implementing grep in Python sounds a bit daunting. @SamMussmann if by phrase you mean the words/phrases in the list, then they'll be at max 4 words, with majority at 1-2 words.

Answer (score 2):

Put the words in a list and after use

```
def intersect(x, y):
    return list(set(x) & set(y))
word_list_text=string.split(text)
words_found={}
words_found=intersect(word_list_text, words)
```

Comment: This solution will not find words containing space such as `Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 0):

let words be the list of words you want  to search and paragraph(the give paragraph of info)
where you want to search the words for

```
for i in words:
    if i in paragraph:
        print i
```

this code is good for the paragraph and words in your question,but mind you this code will print stack if we have stackoverflow and no stack(individually) , this is both a advantage and a disadvantage ,depends on your purpose,
if you want it for individual words use this

```
y=paragraph.split()
for i in words:
    if i in y:
        print i
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `in` instead of `__contains__`?  `in` will call `__contains__` under the hood, and is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the phrases as:

```
phrases = ['Stack','Overflow','Stack Overflow','Stack Exchange','Exchange']
```

then the text as:

```
text = """Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Here are some words which should match:Stack, Exchange."""
```

The following then can be done:

```
found_words = [word for word in phrases if word in text]
```

This will then eliminate the other phrases if they are not in the text.  Though this will also Overflow in addition to the ones specified.