# How to search a string for multiple substrings

Tags: c++, string, optimization, substring, time-complexity

I need to check a short string for matches with a list of substrings. Currently, I do this like shown below ([working code on ideone](http://ideone.com/xp4v6M))

```
bool ContainsMyWords(const std::wstring& input)
{
    if (std::wstring::npos != input.find(L"white"))
        return true;
    if (std::wstring::npos != input.find(L"black"))
        return true;
    if (std::wstring::npos != input.find(L"green"))
        return true;
    // ...
    return false;
}


int main() {
  std::wstring input1 = L"any text goes here";
  std::wstring input2 = L"any text goes here black";

  std::cout << "input1 " << ContainsMyWords(input1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "input2 " << ContainsMyWords(input2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have 10-20 substrings that I need to match against an input. My goal is to optimize code for CPU utilization and reduce time complexity for an average case. I receive input strings at a rate of 10 Hz, with bursts to 10 kHz (which is what I am worried about).

There is [agrep](https://www.tgries.de/agrep/) library with source code written in C, I wonder if there is a standard equivalent in C++. From a quick look, it may be a bit difficult (but doable) to integrate it with what I have.

Is there a better way to match an input string against a set of predefined substrings in C++?

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/738a7aaf8b4910ad) proably has the same performance but IMHO it is easier to read/maintain.

Comment: Bug in code (forgot to compare against `std::string::npos`).  [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9eb2a6183836ccc9) example works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find multiple string matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260962/algorithm-to-find-multiple-string-matches)

Comment: do you need to match `"textblack"` (i.e. no space)?

Comment: @appleapple no, each word is delimited. `textblack` - should not be matched, `text black` - should be matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one big if, instead of several if statements. However, Nathan's Oliver solution with [std::any_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/any_of/) is faster than that though, when making the array of the substrings `static` (so that they do not get to be recreated again and again), as shown below.

```
bool ContainsMyWordsNathan(const std::wstring& input)
{
    // do not forget to make the array static!
    static std::wstring keywords[] = {L"white",L"black",L"green", ...};
    return std::any_of(std::begin(keywords), std::end(keywords),
      [&](const std::wstring& str){return input.find(str) != std::string::npos;});
}
```

---

PS: As discussed in [Algorithm to find multiple string matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260962/algorithm-to-find-multiple-string-matches):

The "grep" family implement the multi-string search in a very efficient way. If you can use them as external programs, do it.

Comment: You are right, one big if works faster but there is nothing to do with branch predictor: one big if is a number of NESTED ifs, not sequence of ifs.

Comment: You are still comparing one big IF vs a sequence of IFs. "if (a||b) {}" is not the same as "if (a) {} ;if (b) {}" it is "if (a) {} else { if (b) {} }". Do you see the difference?

Comment: @gsamaras, Please give any hint why cannot I use std::wstring keywords[] as the argument?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to use a regular expression search, if you use the following regular expression:

```
"(white)|(black)|(green)"
```

that way, with only one pass over the string, you'll get in group 1 if a match was found for the `"white"` substring (and beginning and end points), in group 2 if a match of the `"black"` substring (and beginning and end points), and in group 3 if a match of the `"green"` substring.  As you get, from group 0 the position of the end of the match, you can begin a new search to look for more matches, and everything in one pass over the string!!!