# Using std::search to search substrings in a std::string

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, substring, stdstring

I want to search in a string some substrings using `std::search`.

I tried this:

```
std::string str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
std::string substr[] = { "fox","dog","bear" };
auto it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), substr, substr + 3);
std::cout << "substring found at position :" << (it - str.begin()) << std::endl;
```

And I have these errors :

```
operator_surrogate_func:no mathing overloaded function found
Failed to specialize function template 'unknown type std::equal_to<void>::operator()
```

Comment: What `std::search()` is doing in this case is attempting to compare individual characters to std::strings, which is not possible, hence the error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003410/how-to-search-a-string-for-multiple-substrings

Comment: `std::search` searches for **one** string. If you want to search for three strings from an array you need to use `std::search` and a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of substrings so you need to compare each one individually, `std::search` can only look for one substring at a time.

```
std::string str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
std::string substr[] = { "fox","dog","bear" };

for(auto& sstr : substr){
    auto it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), sstr.begin(), sstr.end());
    std::cout << "substring found at position :" << (it - str.begin()) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that if the substring is not found the return will be the `.end()` iterator which points to one past the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Because last two arguments of `std::search` should be the iterators to the sequence of characters (to be more precise, your iterators, and reference types of your iterators must be comparable) you are looking for, and your `substr` variable if an array of `std::string`. So range `[substr, substr+3)` doesn't actually represent your "fox" or "dog" or "bear, but the pointers to string "fox" and a pointer past the end of your array.

Try the following:

```
    std::string str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    std::string substr[] = { "fox","dog","bear" };
    auto it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), substr[0].begin(), substr[0].end());
    std::cout << "substring found at position :" << (it - str.begin()) << std::endl;
    it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), substr[1].begin(), substr[1].end());
    std::cout << "substring found at position :" << (it - str.begin()) << std::endl;
    it = std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), substr[2].begin(), substr[2].end());
    std::cout << "substring found at position :" << (it - str.begin()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
```

First it will search your string for the occurence of "fox", then "dog" and then "bear". The "bear" is not found and the resulting iterator points to `str.end()`.