# Comparing Two List of Strings

Tags: python, list, python-3.5, string-comparison

I'm familiar with comparing 2 lists of integers and string; however, when comparing 2 lists of strings with extra characters involved can be a little challenging.

Assume the output contains the following where I break it into a list of string. 
 I called it diff in my code.

**Output**

```
164c164
< Apples = 
---
> Apples = 0
168c168
< Berries = 
---
> Berries = false
218c218
< Cherries = 
---
> Cherries = 20
223c223
< Bananas = 
---
> Bananas = 10
233,234c233,234
< Lemons = 2
< Strawberries = 4
---
> Lemons = 4
> Strawberries = 2
264c264
< Watermelons = 
---
> Watermelons = 524288
```

The second set of string contains the ignore variable where I wanted the first list to be compared against.

```
>>> ignore
['Apples', 'Lemons']
```

My code:

```
>>> def str_compare (ignore, output):
...     flag = 0
...     diff = output.strip ().split ('\n')
...     if ignore:
...         for line in diff:
...             for i in ignore:
...                 if i in line:
...                     flag = 1
...             if flag:
...                 flag = 0
...             else:
...                 print (line)
... 
>>>
```

The code works with Apple and Lemons omitted.

```
>>> str_compare(ignore, output)
164c164
---
168c168
< Berries = 
---
> Berries = false
218c218
< Cherries = 
---
> Cherries = 20
223c223
< Bananas = 
---
> Bananas = 10
233,234c233,234
< Strawberries = 4
---
> Strawberries = 2
264c264
< Watermelons = 
---
> Watermelons = 524288
>>>
```

There must be a better way to compare 2 strings that it's not O(n^2).  Had my diff list doesn't contain extra characters like "Apples =" then comparing the two lists can be achieved with O(n).  Any suggestions or ideas to compare without looping through the "ignore" variable on every diff element?

**Update #1**
To avoid confusion and using the suggested comment, I've updated the code.

```
>>> def str_compare (ignore, output):
...     diff = output.strip ().split ('\n')
...     if ignore:
...         for line in diff:
...             if not any ([i in line for i in ignore]):
...                 print (line)
...                 print ("---")
>>>
```

Regardless, it still loop through ignore twice for every diff element.

Comment: I'm confused, why not just use `if not any([i in line for i in ignore]): print(line)` instead of using `flag`

Comment: what is n. useSET OR DICT for speed

Comment: @RockyLi, doing so you'll have everything printed twice since it loops through the ignore list twice.

Comment: No it does not. replace everything under `for line in diff:` with that snippet and it will just print once. Granted, this doesn't answer your question because it's still O(n^2), but if that's your worry you can use a `set`, because `set` operations are completed in O(1) time.

Comment: @RockyLi, my comment was before you edited your comment to if any.  If using if any, then there's no need for flag but it's still 2 nested for loop.

Comment: check the answer for one loop. set are faster due efficient hashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for efficiency use ignore sets not list. Use split to get the key word fromline.

```
>>> def str_compare (ignore, output):
...     ignore = set (ignore)
...     diff = output.strip ().split ('\n')
...     for line in diff:
...         if line.startswith('<') or line.startswith('>'):
...             var = line.split () [1]
...             if var not in ignore:
...                 print (line)
...         else:
...             print (line)
...
```

**Output**

```
>>> str_compare (ignore, output)
164c164
---
168c168
< Berries = 
---
> Berries = false
218c218
< Cherries = 
---
> Cherries = 20
223c223
< Bananas = 
---
> Bananas = 10
233,234c233,234
< Strawberries = 4
---
> Strawberries = 2
264c264
< Watermelons = 
---
> Watermelons = 524288
```

You can eliminate need for flag by splitting and joing over "---\n" (slightly more general solution than flags or typin ----)

Note that string inclusion s1 in s2 worst case should be about len(s1) * len(2), while equality about max(len(s1),len(s2). While python implementation is pretty decent (for average case), linear complexity algos seem to exist  http://monge.univ-mlv.fr/~mac/Articles-PDF/CP-1991-jacm.pdf
See also [Algorithm to find multiple string matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260962/algorithm-to-find-multiple-string-matches)

Comment: without flag it leaves numbers out